# Tomcat shutting down unexpectedly without trace

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

First of all I must say that I have reviewed all related posts but was unable to find a working solution.

I have Tomcat 8.5.6 running on Centos 7.

I have an API which runs on Tomcat (8080, 8009, 8443) which ran for a long time without hiccups. Last week I had to create a new API and problems started: Tomcat shutting down unexpectedly leaving no trace. I tried using port 8007 (forwarded to port 8443) for the new api. Both apis worked but Tomcat kept shutting down. I tried using 8081 but was unable to create a connection on it.

Finally I decided to install a new Tomcat instance on port 8081 but was unable to make the new api work on the new Tomcat (port 8081, 8007 and 8444).

I have disabled the shutdown port (-1) for the Tomcat where the first api is running and stopped the 2nd Tomcat (so I only have 1 Tomcat running now) and have rolled back every change I had made but Tomcat keeps shutting down.

From the Catalina.out log I can't tell much (it doesn't say anything about shutting down). It just has the end the of the startup and the following restart (that I have to order everytime that I realize that it is down):

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST


Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI

09-May-2017 22:44:01.315 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/myapi-api.war has finished in 40,056 ms

09-May-2017 22:44:01.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/manager

09-May-2017 22:44:01.363 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/manager has finished in 47 ms

09-May-2017 22:44:01.363 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/ROOT_

09-May-2017 22:44:01.385 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/ROOT_ has finished in 22 ms

09-May-2017 22:44:01.385 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/ROOT

09-May-2017 22:44:01.395 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/ROOT has finished in 10 ms

09-May-2017 22:44:01.403 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]

09-May-2017 22:44:01.409 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]

09-May-2017 22:44:01.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 40230 ms



10-May-2017 08:22:08.631 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        My App Server

10-May-2017 08:22:08.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 1 2016 00:00:00 UTC

10-May-2017 08:22:08.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         1.0.0.0

10-May-2017 08:22:08.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux

10-May-2017 08:22:08.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64

10-May-2017 08:22:08.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64

10-May-2017 08:22:08.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/jre

10-May-2017 08:22:08.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_112-b15

10-May-2017 08:22:08.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation

10-May-2017 08:22:08.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6

10-May-2017 08:22:08.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6

10-May-2017 08:22:08.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/conf/logging.properties

10-May-2017 08:22:08.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

10-May-2017 08:22:08.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

10-May-2017 08:22:08.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources

10-May-2017 08:22:08.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6

10-May-2017 08:22:08.666 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6

10-May-2017 08:22:08.666 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/temp

10-May-2017 08:22:08.666 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

10-May-2017 08:22:08.991 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

10-May-2017 08:22:09.022 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

10-May-2017 08:22:09.024 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

10-May-2017 08:22:09.026 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
10-May-2017 08:22:09.026 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1112 ms

10-May-2017 08:22:09.061 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina

10-May-2017 08:22:09.062 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: My App Server

10-May-2017 08:22:09.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/tomcat-8.5.6/webapps/myapi-api.war
```

I am new to Tomcat and Centos but I have been working on a solution for this for many days without luck and I am clueless on why I started having problems when I deployed a new api.

I am not sure if this info is enough for an analysis but I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt we can help much, but have you check the system logs to see if the operating system is killing Tomcat?  (Google for "oom killer")

Comment: Check if a _hs_err_pid_*  file has been generated : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html

Comment: Start it with `catalina.sh run` and check the output on std, maybe it will give you a clue as to what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Thank guys for your comments. I don't know why but there were several Tomcat processes open. I restarted the server, started Tomcat and everything seems to be working fine now with only 1 Tomcat process.

Thanks once again!